# How log scale works in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to understand why the equation doesn't give the desired result.

I am unable to decode how this returns 90.96? Even with using the equation **log y = m log x + log k** I can't get the same result. using ∆log y divided by  ∆log x to get **m**.

```
const logScale = d3.scaleLog()
                   .domain([1, 1000])
                   .range([10, 100]);

console.log(logScale(500)); // returns 90.96
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Log scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#log-scales) have the form y = m log(x) + b. By default it's a base 10 log. With your scale

```js
const logScale = d3.scaleLog()
  .domain([1, 1000])
  .range([10, 100]);
```

m = 30 and b = 10. So you can think of it as

```
function logScale(x) {
  return 30 * Math.log10(x) + 10;
}
```

---

Edit: explaining how I got the b = 10 and m = 30

From the domain and range, we know that `logScale(1) === 10`. We also know that `Math.log10(1) === 0`. Therefore, when x is 1 and y is 10, the equation y = m * log(x) + b becomes 10 = m * 0 + b, so we know that b is 10. Now we can plug another (x, y) pair in to get m. For example, we can choose the max values from the domain and range: 100 = m * log(1000) + 10. Thus, m = 90 / log(1000), which is 30.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but what I can't understand is how did you get m = 30? because I assume m = change in the value of y / change in the value of x. so m should be 100-10 / 1000-1, no?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how I got m and b.